# 'todavía (no)' but only meaning '(not) yet'

Tags: selección-de-palabras

Hola vosotros / Hello folks,

So, I have the following question/problem:

**`Is there any way (word or else) to say the same as '(not) yet'?`** , so e.g. to say that you plan on learning sth while saying that you can't do it and haven't tried it yet/up to now.

Because from what I know, 'todavía ' means both 'up to now' (or similar) **and** 'not yet' (or similar),

which can result in rather big differences in meaning of a sentence, depending on the other person's / recipient's interpretation (e.g. always having failed sth <> never ever having tried it).

Thank you in advance.

If there is really no way of expressing this without an extra sentence, so be it, but yeah.

Comment: Can you give us an example which you find ambiguous? In most cases your two translations have a similar meaning.

Comment: *up to now* is **hasta ahora**.

Comment: not = no ; yet = aún/todavía. CERO ambigüedad con eso.